# What is the correct pronunciation of such words as “leur”, “leurs”, “je meurs”, “il meurt”?

Tags: prononciation

I’m having trouble pronouncing the “œ” sound in these words. It sounds to me like it’s in between “a” and “u”.

Comment: What can we do to help on that matter ?

Comment: @Eria Actually, I was wondering to which vowel in English the “œ” sound is closest to. {a, i, u, e, o}

Comment: If you pronounce it as "a" (the english article in "a cat"), this is fine

Comment: I would use forvo.com for things like this. Reverso also has native pronunciations for every word in its database.

Comment: [Project Shtooka](http://shtooka.net/listen/fra/leur) is a multilingual database of audio recordings of words and sentences. Audio files are said by real people. It is used by by wiktionary whenever they give the audio of the words.

Comment: It'd be like how you pronounce the "ea" part in *pearl*, I'd say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some dictionaries have audio pronunciation.

[Check this one for example.](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/leur/)

Answer (score 1):

Think about "hour". Split it in two syllables. What you are looking for is exactly the second one.

You can have a look [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hour), or [here](https://translate.google.fr/#en/fr/hour) if you need.